# how to copy cell values x times according to x number of rows

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to vba and I would appreciate your help.

I have this `Receipt` sheet with some client info, and managed to create a macro that adds a new product line every time it's executed.

[image: Receipt sheet]

But I'd like to run a macro that copies this information to a `Report` sheet in a way that it copies the product lines previously added and the client information 'x' times according to the product lines copied. And the same thing for the next receipts, so the `Report` Sheet would look something like this.

[image: Report Sheet]

As you can see I added 3 products for "John" and added 2 products for "Walter" so their  info was copied 3 and 2 times respectively.

I don't even know if this is possible to do in vba so any of your suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please insert your sample tables as text instead of images so that we can help you faster. And please include examples of what you have tried already and your VBA code, see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your receipt sheet looks in general, so I will build the code on your screens:

```
 Sub CopyData()
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long, firstName As String, lastname As String, _
        dt As String, id As Long, no As Long
    Dim wsReceipt As Worksheet, wsReport As Worksheet
    Set wsReceipt = Worksheets("Receipt worksheet")
    Set wsReport = Worksheets("Report worksheet")
    'gather information from receipt sheet
    no = wsReceipt.Cells(1, 2).Value
    dt = wsReceipt.Cells(2, 2).Value
    id = wsReceipt.Cells(3, 2).Value
    firstName = wsReceipt.Cells(4, 2).Value
    lastname = wsReceipt.Cells(4, 3).Value

    lastRow = wsReceipt.Cells(7, 2).End(xlDown).Row
    'loop through receiptSheet and past all information to reportSheet
    For i = 7 To lastRow
        wsReport.Cells(i - 5, 1).Value = no
        wsReport.Cells(i - 5, 2).Value = dt
        wsReport.Cells(i - 5, 3).Value = id
        wsReport.Cells(i - 5, 4).Value = firstName
        wsReport.Cells(i - 5, 5).Value = lastname
        wsReport.Cells(i - 5, 6).Value = wsReceipt.Cells(i, 2).Value
        wsReport.Cells(i - 5, 7).Value = wsReceipt.Cells(i, 3).Value
    Next
End Sub
```